# Не работает авторизация после переноса wordpress мультисайт

Tags: wordpress

Делал перенос мультисайта. Изначально работал, допустим, site.ru и new.site.ru в режиме мультисайта.
site.ru - основной и его нужно перенести на old.site.ru, сохранив работу new.site.ru

Я делаю обычный перенос файлов из директории на сервере site.ru в директорию old.site.ru, обновляю БД заменив старые записи для основного сайта (://site.ru) на новые (://old.site.ru); Сериализованые массивы также учтены (https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB)

Домен new.site.ru я также перенаправляю на директорию old.site.ru

Всё заработало. old.site.ru работает, new.site.ru - тоже, именно из директории old.site.ru.

Загвоздка в том, что на new.site.ru я теперь просто не могу авторизоваться. Сайт работает, а авторизация - нет. При этом нет никаких ошибок. Гифку прилагаю. https://i.imgur.com/d6uBhih.gifv

Как такую беду поправить можно?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение проблемы. Проблема в кукисах. Вот тут есть хороший ответ - [ссылка](https://toster.ru/q/304445).

Я лично решил проблему добавлением следующей строки в wp-config.php:

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', strtolower( stripslashes( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) ) );
```